# How to read a file path that contains whitespace?

Tags: android, image, flutter, dart

My save image method:

```
_saveScreen() async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
        _globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
    ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    final result =
        await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(byteData.buffer.asUint8List());
    imageDateList.add('${dateTime.day}.${dateTime.month}.${dateTime.year}');
    prefs.setStringList('imageDateList', imageDateList);
    Navigator.of(context).pop();

    String tmpStringHolder =
        result.toString().split('storage')[1].split(',')[0];
    photoData.addPhoto('storage$tmpStringHolder');
    _toastInfo(result.toString());
  }
```

I'm using these packages to write and read image file :

```
image_picker: ^0.6.0+3
permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
image_gallery_saver: ^1.6.7
path_provider: ^1.5.1+1
```

My project was working perfectly when my app name doesn't have whitespace in its name.
Now I get this error when I try to load my images:

```
'storage/emulated/0/Buttocks%20leg/1611320083489.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, Errno = 2)
```

I try to use other packages but I can't find any solution for this. And I tried to read a path like this but that doesn't work too.

```
Image.file(File('\"storage/emulated/0/Buttocks leg/1611553265363.jpg\"')),
```

As you can see above the way I tried. I get this error when I try this :

```
Cannot open file, path = '"storage/emulated/0/Buttocks leg/1611553265363.jpg"' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

I have to read the file path that contains whitespace in its name, how can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried with this `Image.file(file_path)` ?

Comment: you mean, file_path is this? 'storage/emulated/0/Buttocks%20leg/1611320083489.jpg'

Comment: yes, right You can try with this

Comment: Or please add your image picker code so ill try to help you

Comment: ok i will add picker code

Comment: can't even write like this:  File.image(path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [FileImage](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/FileImage-class.html)

Example:

```
new FileImage(
    new File('/storage/emulated/0/Buttocks leg/1611553265363.jpg')
);
```